# Obter valor do data-img

Tags: php, jquery

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Estou obtendo o valor de data-img quando faço hover na classe .gettoll, mas eu preciso substituir esse valor aqui `content: "<img src='IMAGEM AQUI'>",` quando passar o mouse em cada um dos itens, o problema é que todos estão exibindo a mesma imagem.

> OBS: as `li's` estão dentro de um `while()` usando um carousel eu
>   simplifiquei pra colocar aqui...

Alguém teria alguma ideia de como resolver o problema ?

**JS**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".gettool").hover(function(){
    var imagetooltip = $(this).data("img");

    console.log(imagetooltip);
});

    $(".tooltip").tooltipster({
        animation: "grow",
        contentAsHTML: true,

        content: "<img src='IMAGEM AQUI'>",
        multiple: true
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="gettool tooltip" data-img="images/qualquer.jpg"><img src="images/01.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="gettool tooltip" data-img="images/qualquer.jpg"><img src="images/01.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="gettool tooltip"data-img="images/qualquer.jpg"><img src="images/01.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dê uma olhada aqui nos [métodos desse plugin](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#advanced).

O que lhe está a faltar é:

```
    var novaImagen = '<img src="' + imagetooltip + '" />'
    $(this).tooltipster('content', novaImagen)
    $(this).tooltipster('show');
```

Exemplo sem formatação => http://jsfiddle.net/tVsXY/

Comment: Perfeito! muito obrigado resolveu exatamente o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o seletor `$(this).attr("data-img")` ao invés de `$(this).data("img");`

Comment: Leandro, já testei essa possibilidade anteriormente e o problema continua na mesma.

Answer (score 1):

Chame a tooltip dentro de onde você chama a função de hover e no lugar da 'IMAGEM AQUI coloque a variável que tem o valor do data img. Isso deve resolver.

Comment: quase lá, mas agora quando passo o mouse ele exibe 11 links da mesma imagem e sempre a ultima é a mesma, ou seja ele está abrindo todas por debaixo

Comment: Chama o tooltip só com o parâmetro de content pra ver. Não faz sentido ele trazer 11 links.

Comment: estou tentando só com o parâmetro content abre uma vez só mas o console ainda mostra varios links repetidos content: "imagetooltip" <- não imprime a url

Comment: Você está concatenando? Deveria ficar:
content: "<img src='+ imagetooltip +'>";

Comment: Já havia tentado concatenado também e persiste o mesmo resultado

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".gettool").hover(function(){
    var imagetooltip = $(this).attr("data-img");
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', imagetooltip);
});
```

Estou fazendo assim agora:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tooltip').hover(function(){
        var imagetooltip = $(this).attr('data-img');

        $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
            content: $(this).find('img').attr('src', imagetooltip),
            multiple: true
        });
    });
});
```

mas o tooltip sempre trás a imagem do link anterior em relação ao que eu fiz o .hover()

Comment: Para uma resposta mais completa explique sua solução. Isso vai ajudar pessoas que verem essa pergunta no futuro a entender as várias soluções propostas e a diferença ou semelhança entre elas. Para entender melhor como responder dê uma lida na [**Centra de Ajuda**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Chegamos mais perto, porém não consigo imprimir ainda a imagem dentro do tooltip, mas fora do tooltip sim

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.gettool').hover(function(){
     var imagetooltip = $(this).attr('data-img');
     
     //$(this).find('img').attr('src', imagetooltip);
     
     $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
         content: '<img src="+imagetooltip+">',
         multiple: true
     });
 });
});
`